# PHP connection and query error: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm getting the above error in regards to my statement below, tried multiple fixes from other answers in stack but continue to get the same error :(

this is part of a php code in a user registration form, would like their info to insert in the table

```
if($conn->query( "INSERT INTO users (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$uname', '$pword')")==TRUE){
 echo 'Inserted';
 }else{
 echo 'Not Inserted';
 }
```

i have this other code in a separate file for the $conn

```
function dbConnect(){
 $servername = "x";
 $database = "activity2"; 
 $username  = "root"; 
 $password = "root";
// Create connection
 $conn = new 
mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database); 
// Check connection 
if  ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
} //echo "Connection successful"; //make variable global to access in other 
functions global $conn; return $conn;}
```

Comment: the error is with the creation of `$conn`

Comment: i have this code in a separate function file:
    function dbConnect(){
$servername   = "x";
$database = "activity2";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//echo "Connection successful";
//make variable global to access in other functions
global $conn; 
return $conn;}

Comment: then in the file with the code above, I have global $conn at the top?

Comment: you need `$conn=dbConnect();` before the above

Comment: Do you call dbConnect() at any point?

Comment: hmm, i used:

 $conn=dbConnect();
 if($conn->query( "INSERT INTO users (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$uname', '$pword')")==TRUE){
     echo 'Inserted';
 }else{
     echo 'Not Inserted';
 }

still doesn't work :( but thanks for the swift response

Comment: yes I call dbConnect(); at the very top of my php file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is to create the class that will return a connection:

```html
<?php
//filename: dbConnect.php
class dbConnect
{
 
  public function connect() {
    global $conn;
    
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username  = "root"; 
    $password = "";
    $database = "test";  
   // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database); 
   // Check connection 
   if  ($conn->connect_error) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
   } //echo "Connection successful"; //make variable global to access in other 
   
   return $conn;   
  }
}

?>
```

Now you can execute your sql command in another file:

```html
<?php
require 'dbConnect.php';

 $db = new dbConnect();
 $conn = $db->connect();

 $nome = "Anailton";
 $email = "jose@hotmail.com";
 if($conn->query( "INSERT INTO clientes (NOME, EMAIL) VALUES ('$nome', '$email')")==TRUE){
  echo 'Inserted';
 }else{
  echo 'Not Inserted';
 }

?>
```

Comment: i get the error that $db cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: when i run it, i get Fatal error: Class 'dbConnect' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\activity3\registerHandler.php on line 55

Comment: It is possible to copy the content of the answer and save it as a file dbConnect.php inside the folder C:\xampp\htdocs\activity3  With this I believe that your registerHandler.php will find the dbConnect class. Inside the registerHandler.php (before line 55), use the line require 'dbConnect.php';

Comment: Hi Junior, sorry but weird. It works for my registerHandler file, but on my loginHandler file, when i require dbConnect.php it gives me an error that i "cannot redeclare class dbConnect"

Comment: It's possible to use **require_once** instead of require.Use it in every PHP file you need to establish a connection to the database.